# Laravel profile photos show only sometimes

Tags: laravel, photo

I have a profile photo set up in a std header like so

```
<img src="{{ Auth::user()->profile_photo_url }}" class="img-circle" alt="User Image" />
```

When I sign in and land on my dashboard page using this header everything works great.

When I route to any other screen using the same header the picture does not show.

If I inspect the img src I get the same img src from all screens wether the picture shows up or not.

Any insight would help.

```
<img src="storage/profile-photos/1715359786021735.png" class="user-image" alt="User Image">
```

Comment: Add a slash `/` before the uri. Le: `src="/{{ Auth::user()->profile_photo_url }}"`

Comment: Or use the [asset()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-asset) helper